# Do database client libraries use HTTP to talk to the database servers?

Tags: database, server, client

In general - If I use a library in my programming language (NodeJS, C#, Java, etc) to communicate with a database (or similar performance sensitive client/server relationship - PSQL, MSQL, Redis, RabbitMQ), how does the client library usually talk to the server application?

Is it just an HTTP API? Do they have some kind of custom protocol over TCP?

Comment: It can use any protocol (binary or other) to send and retrieve data. It may be network optimized or not can be HTTP-based or not too.